# PHP Excel can't save on folder

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to save my excel file to my server.

Folder location is **public_html/PHPExcel/generated/**

Please see code below:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="filename.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'public_html/PHPExcel/generated/filename.xls',__FILE__));
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you use str_replace? `$objWriter->save('/public_html/PHPExcel/generated/filename.xls');` shoud be enough, just take care of leading `/` to make absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact error that you are getting. I'd also suggest building the path before you do the save so you can see exactly what it is to make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
$filename= 'xyz.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$file = "file.csv";
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$file);
$objWriter->save('php://output', 'w');
```